# What are the numbers shown as "Meta Posts" in the history of moderators?

Tags: support, moderator-tools, moderation-history

If I watch my moderation history on *Drupal Answers* I see the following numbers:

- 124 / 202
- 221 / 314

What do those numbers mean?

The number of posts I see in my [meta profile](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/users/199/kiamlaluno) are 247 answers, and 147 questions. None of those numbers is shown in the moderation history.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The tooltip shows *undeleted* meta questions and answers. You're being confused since, as a moderator, you see deleted questions in the profile totals.

[image]